# What is the best way to loop through this JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, foreach

I have a master list of items which is a nested array of objects, I also have a selected list as well..

```js
let masterList = [{
  category_id: 1,
  meta_list: [{
    name: "Cuisine",
    id: "QWEQWEQWE",
    is_multiselect: false,
    item_list: ["Arabian", "Indian"]
  }, {
    name: "Cost for Two",
    id: "SFDFSDASDASDASD",
    is_multiselect: true,
    item_list: [
      "AED 0 - 100",
      "AED 100 - 200",
      "Greater Than AED 200"
    ]
  }]
}, {
  category_id: 2,
  meta_list: [{
    name: "Cat 2",
    id: "cat2",
    is_multiselect: false,
    item_list: ["cat 2 1", "cat 2 2"]
  }, {
    name: "cuisine 2",
    id: "cui2",
    is_multiselect: true,
    item_list: ["cu1", "cu2"]
  }]
}];

let selectedList = [{
  category_id: 1,
  meta_list: [{
    name: "Cuisine",
    id: "QWEQWEQWE",
    is_multiselect: false,
    item_list: ["Arabian"]
  }, {
    name: "Cost for Two",
    id: "SFDFSDASDASDASD",
    is_multiselect: true,
    item_list: [
      "AED 100 - 200",
      "Greater Than AED 200"
    ]
  }]
}, {
  category_id: 2,
  meta_list: [{
    name: "cuisine 2",
    id: "cui2",
    is_multiselect: true,
    item_list: ["cu1"]
  }]
}];
```

Using the masterList and selected list I'd like to have a derivedList
which must look like this

```js
[{
  category_id: 1,
  meta_list: [{
    name: "Cuisine",
    id: "QWEQWEQWE",
    is_multiselect: false,
    item_list: ["Arabian", "Indian"],
    sel_list: ["Arabian"]
  }, {
    name: "Cost for Two",
    id: "SFDFSDASDASDASD",
    is_multiselect: true,
    item_list: [
      "AED 0 - 100",
      "AED 100 - 200",
      "Greater Than AED 200"
    ],
    sel_list: [
      "AED 100 - 200",
      "Greater Than AED 200"
    ]
  }]
}, {
  category_id: 2,
  meta_list: [{
    name: "Cat 2",
    id: "cat2",
    is_multiselect: false,
    item_list: ["cat 2 1", "cat 2 2"],
    sel_list: ["cat 2 2"]
  }, {
    name: "cuisine 2",
    id: "cui2",
    is_multiselect: true,
    item_list: ["cu1", "cu2"],
    sel_list: ["cu1"]
  }]
}];
```

I would like to have the desiredList with the same items and structure as the masterList, except it would have another property `sel_list`, whose value will be the corresponding value of `item_list` in the `selected_list` array.

The difference in the `masterList` and the `selectedList` is that `item_list` property in the `selectedList` is a subset of `item_list` in the `masterList`

As you can see in the example, the `masterList` could also have an additional item

```js
{
  name: "Cat 2",
  id: "cat2",
  is_multiselect: false,
  item_list: ["cat 2 1", "cat 2 2"],
}
```

```js
[{
  category_id: 1,
  meta_list: [{
    name: "Cuisine",
    id: "QWEQWEQWE",
    is_multiselect: false,
    item_list: ["Arabian", "Indian"],
    sel_list: ["Arabian"]
  }, {
    name: "Cost for Two",
    id: "SFDFSDASDASDASD",
    is_multiselect: true,
    item_list: [
      "AED 0 - 100",
      "AED 100 - 200",
      "Greater Than AED 200"
    ],
    sel_list: [
      "AED 100 - 200",
      "Greater Than AED 200"
    ]
  }]
}, {
  category_id: 2,
  meta_list: [{
    name: "Cat 2",
    id: "cat2",
    is_multiselect: false,
    item_list: ["cat 2 1", "cat 2 2"],
    sel_list: ["cat 2 2"]
  }, {
    name: "cuisine 2",
    id: "cui2",
    is_multiselect: true,
    item_list: ["cu1", "cu2"],
    sel_list: ["cu1"]
  }]
}]
```

which is not in the `selectedList`.

How do I achieve this?

Edit : I am currently doing this like this

```js
masterList.forEach(cat_met_item => {
  selectedList.forEach(filled_cat_met_item => {
    if (cat_met_item.category_id === filled_cat_met_item.category_id) {
      cat_met_item.meta_list.forEach(met_item => {
        filled_cat_met_item.meta_list.forEach(filled_met_item => {
          if (met_item.id === filled_met_item.id) {
            met_item["list"] = filled_met_item["item_list"];
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Using 4 forEach loops. I don't find my method efficient and very messy, so is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have added code snippet as to how I am achieving this. Please reconsider.

Comment: you can use jsonArray.filter(function (el) {return condition;}) instead of loop to fetch desired object so it can reduce nested looping significantly.

Comment: @D.Pareek Can you demonstrate how I would make use of filter in the use case that I have mentioned above?

Comment: Little tip: Consider using regular for loops if you care about performance, they are way faster than any other Higher-Order function (forEach, map, reduce, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

Using json filter method:

```js
let masterList = [
                {
                    category_id: 1,
                    meta_list: [
                        {
                            name: "Cuisine",
                            id: "QWEQWEQWE",
                            is_multiselect: false,
                            item_list: ["Arabian", "Indian"]
                        },

                        {
                            name: "Cost for Two",
                            id: "SFDFSDASDASDASD",
                            is_multiselect: true,
                            item_list: [
                                "AED 0 - 100",
                                "AED 100 - 200",
                                "Greater Than AED 200"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    category_id: 2,
                    meta_list: [
                        {
                            name: "Cat 2",
                            id: "cat2",
                            is_multiselect: false,
                            item_list: ["cat 2 1", "cat 2 2"]
                        },

                        {
                            name: "cuisine 2",
                            id: "cui2",
                            is_multiselect: true,
                            item_list: ["cu1", "cu2"]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ];

      let selectedList = [
                        {
                            category_id: 1,
                            meta_list: [
                                {
                                    name: "Cuisine",
                                    id: "QWEQWEQWE",
                                    is_multiselect: false,
                                    item_list: ["Arabian"]
                                },
                                {
                                    name: "Cost for Two",
                                    id: "SFDFSDASDASDASD",
                                    is_multiselect: true,
                                    item_list: [
                                        "AED 100 - 200",
                                        "Greater Than AED 200"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            category_id: 2,
                            meta_list: [
                                {
                                    name: "cuisine 2",
                                    id: "cui2",
                                    is_multiselect: true,
                                    item_list: ["cu1"]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ];

masterList.forEach(cat_met_item => {
  var obj = selectedList.filter(function (el) {
    return cat_met_item.category_id === el.category_id;
    
  })
  cat_met_item.meta_list.forEach(met_item => {
      var selObj = obj[0].meta_list.filter(function (el) {
      return met_item.id === el.id;
    });
    if (selObj[0]) {
      met_item['sel_list'] = selObj[0].item_list;
    }
    else {
      met_item['sel_list'] = met_item.item_list[met_item.item_list.length - 1];
    }
  });
});

console.log(masterList);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) may be better in this case.

```js
let masterList = [
                {
                    category_id: 1,
                    meta_list: [
                        {
                            name: "Cuisine",
                            id: "QWEQWEQWE",
                            is_multiselect: false,
                            item_list: ["Arabian", "Indian"]
                        },

                        {
                            name: "Cost for Two",
                            id: "SFDFSDASDASDASD",
                            is_multiselect: true,
                            item_list: [
                                "AED 0 - 100",
                                "AED 100 - 200",
                                "Greater Than AED 200"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    category_id: 2,
                    meta_list: [
                        {
                            name: "Cat 2",
                            id: "cat2",
                            is_multiselect: false,
                            item_list: ["cat 2 1", "cat 2 2"]
                        },

                        {
                            name: "cuisine 2",
                            id: "cui2",
                            is_multiselect: true,
                            item_list: ["cu1", "cu2"]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ];

      let selectedList = [
                        {
                            category_id: 1,
                            meta_list: [
                                {
                                    name: "Cuisine",
                                    id: "QWEQWEQWE",
                                    is_multiselect: false,
                                    item_list: ["Arabian"]
                                },
                                {
                                    name: "Cost for Two",
                                    id: "SFDFSDASDASDASD",
                                    is_multiselect: true,
                                    item_list: [
                                        "AED 100 - 200",
                                        "Greater Than AED 200"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            category_id: 2,
                            meta_list: [
                                {
                                    name: "cuisine 2",
                                    id: "cui2",
                                    is_multiselect: true,
                                    item_list: ["cu1"]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ];

masterList.forEach(master_item => {
  let select_item = selectedList.find((el) => master_item.category_id === el.category_id);
  master_item.meta_list.forEach(met_item => {
    let select_meta = select_item.meta_list.find((el) => met_item.id === el.id);
    if (select_meta) {
      met_item.sel_list = select_meta.item_list;
    } else {
      met_item.sel_list = [met_item.item_list[met_item.item_list.length - 1]];
    }
  });
});
console.log(masterList)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `reduce` to iterate and `find` to get the item you need. The following code also handles missing selected/meta_list items.

```js
const exampleMasterList = [
  {
    category_id: 1,
    meta_list: [
      {
        name: 'Cuisine',
        id: 'QWEQWEQWE',
        is_multiselect: false,
        item_list: ['Arabian', 'Indian']
      },

      {
        name: 'Cost for Two',
        id: 'SFDFSDASDASDASD',
        is_multiselect: true,
        item_list: ['AED 0 - 100', 'AED 100 - 200', 'Greater Than AED 200']
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    category_id: 2,
    meta_list: [
      {
        name: 'Cat 2',
        id: 'cat2',
        is_multiselect: false,
        item_list: ['cat 2 1', 'cat 2 2']
      },

      {
        name: 'cuisine 2',
        id: 'cui2',
        is_multiselect: true,
        item_list: ['cu1', 'cu2']
      }
    ]
  }
];

const exampleSelectedList = [
  {
    category_id: 1,
    meta_list: [
      {
        name: 'Cuisine',
        id: 'QWEQWEQWE',
        is_multiselect: false,
        item_list: ['Arabian']
      },
      {
        name: 'Cost for Two',
        id: 'SFDFSDASDASDASD',
        is_multiselect: true,
        item_list: ['AED 100 - 200', 'Greater Than AED 200']
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    category_id: 2,
    meta_list: [
      {
        name: 'cuisine 2',
        id: 'cui2',
        is_multiselect: true,
        item_list: ['cu1']
      }
    ]
  }
];

const getDesiredList = (masterList, selectedList) =>
  masterList.reduce((a, c) => {
    const selectedItem = selectedList.find(ent => ent.category_id === c.category_id);

    return [
      ...a,
      {
        ...c,
        meta_list: c.meta_list.reduce((a2, c2) => {
          const meta_list_item = selectedItem && selectedItem.meta_list.find(ent => ent.id === c2.id);

          return [
            ...a2,
            {
              ...c2,
              sel_list: meta_list_item ? meta_list_item.item_list : []
            }
          ];
        }, [])
      }
    ];
  }, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(getDesiredList(exampleMasterList, exampleSelectedList), null, 2));
```

Comment: Almost perfect, I like that it doesn't alter the original data structure.
`reduce` can be simplified to `map` here.
Also, the result isn't correct, the code should be:
`sel_list: meta_list_item ? meta_list_item.item_list : [ c2.item_list[c2.item_list.length - 1] ]`.

Answer (score 2):

I would just Deep clone both objects using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(_))` and then copy any properties that exist in `selectedList` and not in `masterList` to the cloned copy of the `masterList` object.

Since you are dealing with strings (because of `JSON.stringify`) you can just replace `item_list` with `sel_list` using `String#replace`.

The last problem now is matching the array items of `masterList` with the respective ones in `selectedList`. One way would be to just use `index` but that is obviously not very safe or reliable. I would reccomend supplying a function to the method that does the merging, that will accept an item from each array and will determine if they are `equal`. This function will also have to be able to understand which array you are referring to (i.e. `masterList`, `meta_list`, `item_list`...).

Here is a fairly abstract solution to your problem, the only custom part are the last 5 lines at the end that replace the `item_list` to `sel_list` and manage the array matching, everything else is reusable. (I have already converted the two object into strings to save vertical space and you can focus on the solution, rather than scrolling down to it).

```js
let masterList = `[{"category_id":1,"meta_list":[{"name":"Cuisine","id":"QWEQWEQWE","is_multiselect":false,"item_list":["Arabian","Indian"]},{"name":"Cost for Two","id":"SFDFSDASDASDASD","is_multiselect":true,"item_list":["AED 0 - 100","AED 100 - 200","Greater Than AED 200"]}]},{"category_id":2,"meta_list":[{"name":"Cat 2","id":"cat2","is_multiselect":false,"item_list":["cat 2 1","cat 2 2"]},{"name":"cuisine 2","id":"cui2","is_multiselect":true,"item_list":["cu1","cu2"]}]}]`;
let selectedList = `[{"category_id":1,"meta_list":[{"name":"Cuisine","id":"QWEQWEQWE","is_multiselect":false,"item_list":["Arabian"]},{"name":"Cost for Two","id":"SFDFSDASDASDASD","is_multiselect":true,"item_list":["AED 100 - 200","Greater Than AED 200"]}]},{"category_id":2,"meta_list":[{"name":"cuisine 2","id":"cui2","is_multiselect":true,"item_list":["cu1"]}]}]`;

/**
 * Deep merges 2 objects (if a property exists for both objects then only the original will be used)
 * @param {{} | string} original Original object in object or json format
 * @param {{} | string} other Other object in object or json format
 * @param {(original: string | {}, other: string | {}) => boolean} manageList Function called to compare items in the arrays
 * @returns {{}} 
 */
function mergeJSONs(original, other, manageList) {
  original = typeof original === "string" ? original : JSON.stringify(original); // Deep clone both objects
  other = typeof other === "string" ? other : JSON.stringify(other);
  return recursiveMerge(JSON.parse(original), JSON.parse(other), manageList);
}

/**
 * Copies all the properties that exist in the `other` object to the `original` object
 * @param {{}} original Object to copy the properties to
 * @param {{}} other Object to copy the properties from
 * @param {(original: string | {}, other: string | {}) => boolean} manageList Function called to compare items in the arrays
 * @returns {{}}
 */
function recursiveMerge(original, other, manageList) {
  if (original instanceof Array) {
    if (!(other instanceof Array)) throw Error("Incompatible Types");
    var matchedList = [];
    for (var otherItem of other) {
      var originalIndex = original.findIndex(function(originalItem, index) {
        if (manageList.call(this, originalItem, otherItem) && !matchedList.includes(index)) return matchedList.push(index);
      });
      if (originalIndex === -1) original.push(otherItem);
      else if (typeof otherItem === "object") recursiveMerge(original[originalIndex], otherItem, manageList);
    }
  } else {
    if (other instanceof Array) throw Error("Incompatible Types");
    for (var key in other) {
      if (!(key in original)) original[key] = other[key];
      else if (typeof other[key] === "object") recursiveMerge(original[key], other[key], manageList);
    }
  }
  return original;
}

console.log(mergeJSONs(masterList, selectedList.replace(/"item_list":/g, "\"sel_list\":"), function(original, other) {
  if (typeof original === "string" && typeof other === "string") return original === other;
  else if (typeof original === "object" && typeof other === "object") {
    if ("category_id" in original && "category_id" in other) return original.category_id === other.category_id;
    if ("id" in original && "id" in other) return original.id === other.id;
  }
}));
```

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Mateusz Siniarski, while generating the desired output and replacing `reduce` with `map`.

```
const derivedList = masterList.map(master => {
  const selected = selectedList.find(el => el.category_id === master.category_id)
  return {
    ...master,
    meta_list: master.meta_list.map(meta => {
      const { item_list } = selected.meta_list.find(el => el.id === meta.id) || {}
      return {
        ...meta,
        sel_list: item_list || [ meta.item_list[meta.item_list.length - 1] ]
      }
    })
  }
})
```

An iterative version that mutates `masterList`:

```
masterList.forEach(master => {
  const selected = selectedList.find(el => el.category_id === master.category_id)
  master.meta_list.forEach(meta => {
    const { item_list } = selected.meta_list.find(el => el.id === meta.id) || {}
    meta.sel_list = item_list || [ meta.item_list[meta.item_list.length - 1] ]
  })
})
```